# How to prevent DBCC TRACEON/OFF informational messages in logs?

Tags: sql-server-2012, windows-7

I am not sure this is the appropriate place to post this question, although I arrive to it in the context of writing a relatively complex SQL query. If it is not, please accept my apologies and, if I can abuse your kindness, point me to the appropriate Stack Exchange community where I might find a solution to my problem.

I had to implement a "simple" search; simple for the user to use as it only had one field but rather complicated for me to implement because any expression entered in the search field could be interpreted in quite a few different ways, involving multiple tables and relationships. So I decided to break up the search into simpler queries, each dumping a group of ids based on a specific set of criteria into a table variable. Finally, I would consolidate all the temporary results into a single set, joining in any missing fields and sorting the set according to the user preferences. The results seemed accurate, but at times the performance was surprisingly and unacceptably slow.

After some investigation, I learned that if a table variable is joined with other tables in SQL Server, it may result in slow performance due to inefficient query plan selection because SQL Server does not support statistics or track number of rows in a table variable while compiling a query plan. Apparently, however, I could improve the situation by enabling trace flag 2453, which allows a table variable to trigger recompile when enough number of rows are changed. Indeed, times dropped from approximately 30 seconds to well under 1 second, so I decided to test the trace flag in other queries that use table variables containing potentially many rows.

What I did not expect was that every enabling and disabling of trace flag 2453 would yield an informational event (similar to "DBCC TRACEON 2453, server process ID (SPID) 56. This is an informational message only; no user action is required") both in the SQL Server log and in the operating system event log. But some of the queries in which I have enabled the trace flag are run many times, which is causing those informational messages that require no user action to flood both logs, hiding other potentially useful messages that might require user action.

Through some additional investigation, I have learned that trace flag 2505 can prevent some of these events from being logged, but in my test environment (running SQL Server Express 2012 on Windows 7 SP1) this did not solve my issue.

Does anybody know how to prevent these messages from flooding the logs? Thanks!